# json - See if key exists in nested array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I feel like this is really simple, but how would I check to see if month exists in my jSON data. Using .hasOwnProperty doesn't seem to be working for me. I feel like I'm missing something simple here. All it does is always default to the else clause even though month is clearly in my JSON.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8y7rJ/1/

```
var data={"users":[
{
    name:"Ray",        
    phone:"999-999-9999",
    birthday: {
        month:"January",
        day:12,
        year:2012
    }
},
{
    name:"Joe",        
    phone:"111-999-9999",
    birthday: {
        year:1992
    }
},
{
    name:"James",        
    phone:"111-111-1111",
    birthday: {            
        year:2012
    }
}
]}

if(data.users[0].hasOwnProperty("month")){
    alert('month exists');
} else {
    alert('month does not exist');
}
```

Code samples are appreciated.

Comment: `data.users[0]` doesn't have a property `month`. `data.users[0].birthday` does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`month` is a property inside of `birthday`, so you need to do something like this:

```
if (data.users[0].birthday.month){
    alert('month exists');
} else {
    alert('month does not exist');
}
```

Note that if you're not sure whether `birthday` will always be present, you should do this instead:

```
if (data.users[0].birthday && data.users[0].birthday.month){
    alert('month exists');
} else {
    alert('month does not exist');
}
```